# Database values do not appear during first time use of my application

Tags: android, database, full-text-search

I am creating a database using a DataHelper class and then creating a table using FTS virtual table.
The values are being imported from the text file in RAW folder which contains 1000 entries and a total file size of 64 kB.

But during the first time use the data values are not appearing during  table query as though the full table is not yet created. Perhaps the file size is not at all huge(64 kB). The values appear when i restart the application and again make the query.

Is there any solution for this??

Comment: Surely there is a solution. But some of your code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution: you can package your SQLite database in the APK and copy it on first run.
That way you will avoid long initial population...
More about this solution: [Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Comment: thank you.. I read that article long time before but could not recall it.. Thanks again..